# Phonegap navigator.camera.getPicture() not working inside 'requirejs' function

Tags: ios, cordova, requirejs, cordova-3

I am using [PhoneGap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap) 3.1, [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), and [Backbone.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backbone.js) for my project.

My problem is that `navigator.camera.getPicture()` is not working. If I place the `navigator.camera.getPicture()` function above the `require()` function it will work.
I added this block inside `document.addEventListener('deviceready', success);`
and added the `deviceready` listener inside `requirejs`. Both are not working. How can I fix this problem?

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script data-main="js/main.js" src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
```

**main.js**

```
requirejs(['backbone'], function (Backbone) {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(function () {
        console.log("SUUS");
    }, function () {
        console.log("ERRR");
    }, {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
    });
    Backbone.history.start();
}, false);
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the `deviceready` listener as the first thing? It is the first event to fire and may be what is causing this.

Comment: First begining of the script itself you should write device ready function along with right the above function below it then it wiil definetly works.